# Convert format of datetime to another format of datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

My code parses a raw data and turns it into a datetime string format such as below

```
string birthday  = "20" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + second;
```

So birthday is a string and then I converted it to datetime format such as below

```
DateTime bdaylater= Convert.ToDateTime(birthday);
```

The result became like the one below

```
7/8/2015 5:02:05 AM
```

in which I wanted to convert to something like the one below

```
2015/07/08 05:02:05.000
```

How can I achieve such result.

Thanks.

Comment: google DateTime.Format will give you the formats on how to do this.

Comment: Have a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx and here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should format your date variable before printing the same

```
string birthday  = "2015" + "-" + "07" + "-" + "08" + " " + "05" + ":" + "02" + ":" + "05";
DateTime bdaylater= Convert.ToDateTime(birthday);
Console.WriteLine(bdaylater.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.mmm"));
```

this will give the o/p `2015/07/08 05:02:05.02`

[Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Oek5vA)

If you want only 000 in millisecond the string will be `"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.000"`

Answer (score 1):

Would you like to convert it to string format? With 3 zeros padded on it? Maybe this could help:

```
        int year = 15;
        int month = 7;
        int day = 8;
        int hour = 5;
        int minutes = 2;
        int second = 5;
        string birthday = "20" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + second;
        DateTime bdaylater = Convert.ToDateTime(birthday);
        Console.WriteLine(bdaylater);
        Console.WriteLine(bdaylater.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.000")); //2015/07/08 05:02:05.000
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime.Parse(birthday).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.fff")
```